# Update URL Apps Hosted on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I have an Android app in the Google Play store. I want to send the users to an update URL if they are running previous versions. I am using the following URL and launching it in their browser:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keko.rabbit.ci.humidity

NOTE: Please don't browse the above URL since it is for explanation purposes.

```
UPDATE:
```

When I browse to that address from the device it says "Webpage not available". The webpage at ..... might be temporarly down or it may have moved to a new address.

UPDATE 2:

For some reason it is still not working. And says the same error.

```
Uri uriUrl = getAndroidUpdateURL()); // this returns market://details?id=com.keko.rabbit.ui.humidity
Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
act.startActivity(launchBrowser); 
return;
```

Comment: So what happens when you try? Have you read [Linking To Your Products](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html)?

Comment: Looks like I was using the website URL and not the App URL. If you can post that as an answer I can accept it!

Comment: Is the package name correct? Check your manifest/developer console to make sure. Check the value in the program using a debugger/log statement also. If the app is live on the Play Store, there's no reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, The package name is 100% correct. I used the web URL to browse to that package and it works fine when I am using browser like Chrome on PC.

Comment: If I paste the market://details?.... into the browser even then it picks up and browse to the correct product. But when from within the Anroid app it does not work.

Comment: Just make sure your `Uri` is correct then. I can't see the function that makes it for you. All I see is the code that calls it with a mismatched `)`.

Comment: I tried to browse to Google.com from using the Android Simulator and it even does not work. I am connected to client's internet using ethernet port. I guess the problem is to find a way to allow the Android Simulator to browse the internet.

Comment: Oh. Well, yea then. If you don't have internet access it won't work.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to enable internet access on Android Simulator? I have internet on my PC just not in the browser running inside the simulator.